# ffmpeg: how to set "joint-stereo" mode in mp3?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3

How to set joint-stereo mode in ffmpeg when converting from flac to mp3 format?

Normally I use this command, but it produces "stereo" mode. I need "joint-stereo".

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -vn -ac 2 -ar 44100 -ab 320k -f mp3 output.mp3
```

I am using latest ffmpeg for windows x64.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to all the references I have seen I am pretty sure it should already default to joint stereo mode. But I successfully tested turning joint stereo mode on and off using the `joint_stereo` flag. It should be set to `1` to enable it or `0` to disable it.

Example:

> ffmpeg -i input.flac -vn -ac 2 -ar 44100 -ab 320k -f mp3 -joint_stereo 1 output.mp3

This is based on the documentation I found [here](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#libmp3lame-1)

Comment: which version of ffmpeg did you use?

Comment: @c97: It was the latest static compiled version which I downloaded today. I am running it on Windows. What happens when you try using the flag and do you get an error? If not then do you have an example of a file where this isn't working?

Comment: Do you have libmp3lame enabled?

Comment: I use Zeranoe static x64 build http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win64/static/ffmpeg-20140507-git-4cdea92-win64-static.7z
in this version when I use "-joint_stereo 1" switch it still produces stereo, not joint-stereo. I have compared file created with this switch and without, output files were the same.
FFmpeg did not produce any error. My test file is: http://c97.pl/pliki/11.flac

Comment: @c97: How are you determining whether the files are the same? If I use a binary compare tool, the files have lots of differences. As I understand it, file size should not necessarily change, it would be the quality that changes because you are specifying the same bit-rate. What tool are you using to check the stereo mode? Foobar2000 shows `<MP3_STEREO_MODE>` as being different for the two files.

Comment: This is weird, but now it works. Thank you :)
Foobar (in file properties) shows <MP3_STEREO_MODE> : joint stereo

Comment: I used following command but the output is still joint-stereo not stereo: ffmpeg -i input.flac -vn -ac 2 -ar 44100 -ab 320k -f mp3 output.mp3

Comment: @samsam114 Add `-joint_stereo 0` to your command.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Correction to my original post here (leaving original text for clarity with the comments below). The file encoding is in Joint Stereo when this is selected as the encoding option in ffmpeg. However, the header info is incorrect, showing Stereo instead of Joint Stereo. So, while there is indeed a bug in ffmpeg, fortunately it's limited to the metadata in the header. ffmpeg does get the important part right, and sensitive MP3 players should still work (Joint Stereo is the most widely supported MP3 format).

---

I'm afraid James P is mistaken, at least as recently as ffmpeg 3.4.2, but this is a common misunderstanding. Unfortunately, this is a longstanding bug in the way ffmpeg uses libmp3lame. It sets the header to Joint Stereo, but doesn't actually encode in Joint Stereo. MP3 players that require Joint Stereo will choke on these files. The -joint_stereo 1 option does NOT work as a parameter in ffmpeg. See open bug report: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4954

I use lame or sox to set MP3 files to joint stereo after making other changes with ffmpeg. I wish this were not necessary, especially when working with lossy MP3 files where each action on the files downgrades them a bit, but it's not too bad.

In Windows (this works from CMD not PS), for example, here's a command I use frequently to batch convert and normalize from WAV files to MP3 via ffmpeg and then use SoX to set to Joint Stereo (its default output). One of the easiest checks in Windows for Joint Stereo or Stereo is Mp3tag, and be sure to show the "Mode" column, which will simply say Mono, Stereo, or Joint Stereo. This is also the easiest way to confirm that ffmpeg is not capable of properly outputting in Joint Stereo.

for %x in ("*.wav") do (ffmpeg -i "%x" -ab 320k -f mp3 -af dynaudnorm -id3v2_version 3 "int_%x.mp3" & sox --norm=-2.75 "int_%x.mp3" -c 2 -C 192 "ready-%x.mp3")

I use a higher bitrate for the intermediate file than the final output (320 vs 192 in this case), to minimize audio quality degradation.

Note that this will leave the intermediate files (int*) in the same directory as the original and final (ready*) files.

Comment: This bug still exists as of early 2024 in version 6.1.1 of ffmpeg. FFMPEG is effectively broken for creating MP3 files: Especially if the left and right channels include much overlap, Joint Stereo, which only uses the second channel to carry the delta, therefore provides significantly higher quality audio at any given bitrate than Stereo, which splits the bitrate in half to provide a full left and right channel, even though these may be almost identical. It's also more compatible with older MP3 players, some of which only support Joint Stereo. FFMPEG's Joint Stereo output doesn't work.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say FFmpeg's joint stereo output doesn't work? When I encode an MP3 using FFmpeg and run mp3guessenc on it, it says it's joint stereo.

Comment: On further investigation and checking with the Mp3tag developer, I was wrong (in part). We confirmed that ffmpeg sets the headers incorrectly, which is why apps like Mp3tag believe it's in Stereo rather than Joint Stereo (the headers come out of ffmpeg saying Stereo when they should say Joint Stereo), but the actual file encoding is correctly in Joint Stereo. So there is still a bug in ffmpeg in that it writes the header info incorrectly, but it's not quite as serious as I had believed. 

SoX does encode the file correctly and write the headers correctly, so if you need the header, use SoX.